# Siri Integration in iOS for Payment transfer without specifying payee

Tags: ios, sirikit

I have to integrate Siri in our application for requesting payments without specifying the payer. It's possible to do? how can I do it?

**RequestPaymentIntentHandler**:

```
#import "RequestPaymentIntentHandler.h"

@implementation RequestPaymentIntentHandler

#pragma mark - Resolve

-(void)resolvePayerForRequestPayment:(INRequestPaymentIntent *)intent withCompletion:(void (^)(INPersonResolutionResult * _Nonnull))completion {

    completion([INPersonResolutionResult notRequired]);
}

-(void)resolveNoteForRequestPayment:(INRequestPaymentIntent *)intent withCompletion:(void (^)(INStringResolutionResult * _Nonnull))completion {

    completion([INStringResolutionResult notRequired]);
}

-(void)resolveCurrencyAmountForRequestPayment:(INRequestPaymentIntent *)intent withCompletion:(void (^)(INCurrencyAmountResolutionResult * _Nonnull))completion {

    if (! intent.currencyAmount || intent.currencyAmount.amount.doubleValue <= 0)
        completion([INCurrencyAmountResolutionResult needsValue]);

    else
        completion([INCurrencyAmountResolutionResult successWithResolvedCurrencyAmount:intent.currencyAmount]);
}

#pragma mark - Confirm

-(void)confirmRequestPayment:(INRequestPaymentIntent *)intent completion:(void (^)(INRequestPaymentIntentResponse * _Nonnull))completion {

    if (! intent || ! intent.currencyAmount)
        completion([[INRequestPaymentIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INRequestPaymentIntentResponseCodeFailure userActivity:nil]);

    else
        completion([[INRequestPaymentIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INRequestPaymentIntentResponseCodeSuccess userActivity:nil]);
}

#pragma mark - Handle

-(void)handleRequestPayment:(INRequestPaymentIntent *)intent completion:(void (^)(INRequestPaymentIntentResponse * _Nonnull))completion {

    INRequestPaymentIntentResponse *response;

    if (! intent || ! intent.currencyAmount) {

        NSLog(@"NO INTENT ");

        response = [[INRequestPaymentIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INRequestPaymentIntentResponseCodeFailure userActivity:nil];
        response.paymentRecord = [[INPaymentRecord alloc] initWithPayee:nil payer:nil currencyAmount:intent.currencyAmount paymentMethod:INPaymentMethodTypeUnknown note:nil status:INPaymentStatusFailed feeAmount:nil];

    } else {

        NSLog(@"INTENT VALIDO ");

        response = [[INRequestPaymentIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:INRequestPaymentIntentResponseCodeSuccess userActivity:nil];
        response.paymentRecord = [[INPaymentRecord alloc] initWithPayee:nil payer:nil currencyAmount:intent.currencyAmount paymentMethod:INPaymentMethodTypeUnknown note:nil status:INPaymentStatusCompleted feeAmount:nil];
    }

    completion(response);
}

@end
```

.notRequired in resolvePayerForRequestPayment doesn't work! It seems that intent.payer must exist. In fact, if I utter: "Charge Alex $30" it works but if I utter: "Charge $30" **doesn't work, because Handle method no called**. Siri always tells me to continue in the app. No errors, no warnings, nothing!

intent.payer is readOnly therefore it can not be forced.

**IntentsExtension:**

```
#import "IntentsExtension.h"
#import "RequestPaymentIntentHandler.h"

@implementation IntentsExtension

-(id)handlerForIntent:(INIntent *)intent {

    if ([intent isKindOfClass:[INRequestPaymentIntent class]])
        return [RequestPaymentIntentHandler new];

    return nil;
}


@end
```

Thi is Extension plist file:
[Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF1Qe.png)

target App **AppDelegate**:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    if ([INPreferences siriAuthorizationStatus] != INSiriAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
        [INPreferences requestSiriAuthorization:^(INSiriAuthorizationStatus status) {
        }];

    NSLog(@"--->SIRI LANGUAGE: %@<----", [INPreferences siriLanguageCode]);

    return YES;
}
```

Siri capabilities enabled.

**To recap my goal is to not specify the payer. Any ideas?**

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly does it not work? Are you getting an error? Unexpected behaviour? If so, what exactly?

Comment: I edited my post for clarity